# DotNetBrowser - Exceptions when Upgrading from V1 to V2

Tags: exception, upgrade, chromium, nuget-package, dotnetbrowser

I recently started migrating from a working V1 version of DotNetBrowser from TeamDev, and I ran into multiple issues that have stumped me.

Previously all the Chromium binaries worked well together and were built into the NuGet package. The main downside was launching multiple instances of my application caused the User Directory to get re-used, so I addressed that issue years ago.

I received a new license key back in 2020 for V2, so I figured I'd finally get around to upgrading, since there's a ton of new things to work with now. I upgraded to the latest version, 2.24.1 at the time of this question.

I went through and overhauled all the conversions of Javascript calls/executions to use the new way of things, but the biggest hurdle so far has been just getting the engine to work.

In debug, it takes several minutes for the new EngineFactory.Create call to process. It seems that most of the time is possibly due to downloading or extracting the Chromium dlls. Half the time it returns "RPC call timed out." the other half the time the message says "Cannot perform this operation, because the object is already disposed." When it does work after multiple retries, it does eventually create an IEngine, but when trying to create an IProfile or an IBrowser directly it also hits an exception of "Cannot perform this operation because the connection to Chromium is closed."

Here's the offending snippet called in the constructor:

```
            string base_data_directory = @"C:\test";
            string chromium_directory = base_data_directory + @"\chromium_dir";

            EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions.Builder
            {
                ChromiumDirectory = base_data_directory,
                CrashDumpDirectory = chromium_directory + @"\CrashDump\",
                UserDataDirectory = chromium_directory + @"\User\",
                SandboxDisabled = true
            }.Build();
            IEngine engine = EngineFactory.Create(engineOptions);
```

I don't have any additional instances running, and the initialization time is consistently multiple minutes before the exceptions occur.

After some digging, I read in one of their FAQs that their licenses are only valid for versions released while the license was valid. Although I didn't receive any of their license related exceptions, I figured I'd try to roll back, so I removed the new NuGet packages and installed 2.1.1, which was the last release that occurred during my license range.

The exception did change, but it changed to be "Unable to find or restore compatible Chromium binaries. The compatible binaries were not found in the assembly." and digging through NuGet, they don't seem to have a publicly released version 2.1.1 Chromium package.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I would like to eventually get a new license key, but if the issues with launch time (which is an unacceptable increase in time) and the random RPC / dispose of the Engine while being created I probably will go back to version 1.

Edit 2023.11.03:
I am attaching the main portion of the logs generated per Anna (thanks so much!).

```
    2023-11-03T15:51:20.8094415-07:00  Information      IPC - Current platform: WindowsX64 []
    2023-11-03T15:51:20.8094415-07:00  Information      IPC - .NET version: 4.0.30319.42000 []
    2023-11-03T15:51:21.0369928-07:00  Information      IPC - Assembly version: 2.24.1.3989 []
    2023-11-03T15:51:21.0369928-07:00  Information      IPC - Binaries version: 2.24.1.902 []
    
2023-11-03T15:51:21.1463823-07:00      Warning  Process - [41092:21456:1103/155121.145:WARNING:chrome_main_delegate.cc(615)] This is Chrome version 118.0.5993.70 (not a warning) []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.1880668-07:00      Warning  Process - [41092:21456:1103/155121.148:WARNING:policy_logger.cc(148)] :components\enterprise\browser\controller\chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(88) Could not create policy manager as CBCM is not enabled. []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.1920502-07:00  Information      IPC - Accepting incoming connection... []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3384778-07:00  Information      IPC - Shared memory created. Memory id: 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3404718-07:00  Information      IPC - Accepting incoming connection: Browser, ConnectionId{Uuid: 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee; } []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3474548-07:00  Information      IPC - Accepting socket connections []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3494490-07:00  Information      IPC - Socket connection checker started [SocketConnectionChecker: Connection Browser,ConnectionId{Uuid: 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee; } [Writer : 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee]]
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3594229-07:00      Warning  Process - [41092:21456:1103/155121.353:WARNING:pref_notifier_impl.cc(41)] Pref observer for browser.relaunch_window found at shutdown. []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3594229-07:00      Warning  Process - [41092:21456:1103/155121.353:WARNING:pref_notifier_impl.cc(41)] Pref observer for browser.relaunch_notification_period found at shutdown. []
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3614186-07:00  Information      IPC - System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at DotNetBrowser.Internals.Ipc.Connections.ConnectionChecker.Run() [SocketConnectionChecker: Connection Browser,ConnectionId{Uuid: 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee; } [Writer : 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee]]
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3614186-07:00  Information      IPC - Connection socket closed [SocketConnectionChecker: Connection Browser,ConnectionId{Uuid: 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee; } [Writer : 8ba7a88c-3470-4055-b153-8b7829fc9fee]]
2023-11-03T15:51:21.3614186-07:00  Information  License - One or more product licenses were located []
2023-11-03T15:53:28.0658298-07:00  Information  Process - Chromium process exit code 00000026 []
2023-11-03T15:53:28.0658298-07:00  Information      IPC - Stopping server... []
2023-11-03T15:53:28.0668290-07:00  Information      IPC - Server stopped. []
2023-11-03T15:53:28.0668290-07:00  Information      IPC - Stopping server... [OK] []
2023-11-03T15:53:28.1072106-07:00        Error      IPC - Failed to send RPC request: rpc.EngineFactory.ApplyLicense.
```

Based on that information, it looks like it is calling out and failing when applying the license.

Edit 11/6/2023:

It appears that it wasn't just the User Data Directory that was causing the issue, but the Crash Dump and Chromium directories as well.
I didn't encounter the issue on my Windows 11 PC, but my Windows 10 PC was very angry with me.

I ended up fixing the issue via the following on each associated directory:

```
    private DirectoryInfo MakeDirectoryAndUpdateSecuritySettings(string directory)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        dir.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        DirectorySecurity security = dir.GetAccessControl();
        SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dir.SetAccessControl(security);
        return dir;
    }
```

Thanks again to Anna and Kateryna!

Comment: Please enable the DotNetBrowser logs and attach the output to the question:
```
LoggerProvider.Instance.Level = SourceLevels.All;
LoggerProvider.Instance.FileLoggingEnabled = true;
LoggerProvider.Instance.OutputFile = @"C:\test\dotnetbrowser.log";
```
This code should be put before `EngineFactory.Create()` call.

Comment: As I can understand, you have truncated the logs to remove sensitive information. Did you specify the custom user data directory? Does it point to the writable location? In the logs, there's a command line for Chromium containing the path to the user data as one of its arguments.

Comment: Yes. The custom user data directory is the same directory as the chromium directory with an appended "UserData" folder to the path. Should it be moved out of the Chromium directory and into a separate one? It didn't appear to be needed in the 1x version.

Comment: According to the code snippet, the user data directory is expected to be "C:\test\chromium_dir\User\". The path itself is acceptable, however, you need to check whether this location is writable for the Windows user launching your .NET application.